# Google Web Toolkit: RichTextArea installation for PHP application

Tags: java, gwt

Google Web Toolkit features gwt-RichTextArea, a simple but effective WYSIWYG editor. Now I would like to use this editor in my PHP application but don't know how to implement it. I'm not sure but it seems it's only possible to implement when you're using JAVA. Tell me I'm wrong!

Answer (score 2):

Everything created in GWT is eventually compiled to HTML, javascript, and CSS, so you will be able to use this control even if your app is using PHP. But you will need to know Java to create the initial GWT application with the `RichTextToolbar` control which can then be compiled to Javascript.

See [this guide](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/gettingstarted.html) if you are new to GWT, and [this tutorial](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/) if you are new to Java as well.